# Are element size and count exchangable in an fread call?

Tags: c, function, file, fread

Let's say I have a file with a size of 5000 bytes, which I am trying to read from.

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
  char *file_path[] = "/path/to/my/file"
  FILE *fp= fopen(file_path,"rb"); //open the file
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
  unsigned long fullsize = ftell(fp); //get the file size (5000 for this example)
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); //bring back the stream to the begging  
  char *buf = (char*)malloc(5000);
  fread(buf,5000,1,fp);
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

I can also replace the `fread` call with

```
fread(buf,1000,5,fp);
```

What is better? And why?
In matters of optimization, I understand the return value is different.

Comment: These two pieces of code do different things. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `fread(buf,1000,5,fp)` and `fread(buf,5000,1,fp)`?

Comment: @cad yes. Im trying to work with the data in buf and manipulated him.. some to memcpy, and some to write another file..

Comment: @cad: that was a pretty high value edit :) +1

Comment: I've never understood that either; most developers can multiply two numbers together without the dubious support of passing two 'size' parameters.

Comment: Same thing goes for `void* calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)`.

Comment: @MartinJames And, in case they can't, resorting to the compiler also works. :O

Comment: @cad: Except that `calloc` never allocates less than what you requested (it allocates all of it or fails). For both `calloc` and `fread`, the behavior isn't defined in terms of multiplying the two arguments. Te difference matters when the product would wrap around.

Answer (score 6):

If you exchange those two arguments, you still request to read the same number of bytes. However the behaviour is different in other respects:

- What happens if the file is shorter than that amount
- The return value

Since you should *always* be checking the return value of `fread`, this is important :)

If you use the form `result = fread(buf, 1, 5000, fp);`, i.e. read `5000` units of size `1`, but the file size is only `3000`, then what will happen is that those `3000` bytes are placed in your buffer, and `3000` is returned.

In other words you can detect a partial read and still use the partial result.

However if you use `result = fread(buf, 5000, 1, fp);`, i.e. read `1` unit of size `5000`, then the contents of the buffer are *indeterminate* (i.e. the same status as an uninitialized variable), and the return value is `0`.

In both cases, a partial read leaves the file pointer in an indeterminate state, i.e. you will need to `fseek` before doing any further reads.

Using the latter form (i.e. any size other than `1`) is probably  best used for when you either want to abort if the full size is not available, or if you're reading a file with fixed-size records.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it best to use `1` for the element size. If `fread()`
can't read a complete element at the end of the file, it will skip the
last, partial element. This is not desirable when the last element is
short. On the other hand, using `1` for element size does no harm.

Sample code that prints itself and demonstrates this behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define N 1

int main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    int ct;
    char buf[SIZE * N + 1];

    fin = fopen("size_n.c", "r");

    while (1) {
        ct = fread(buf, SIZE, N, fin);
        if (!ct)
            break;
        buf[ct * SIZE] = '\0';
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example – since you are reading `char`s – the element size actually *is* 1. But if you were reading, say, an array of `double`s, not reading the “last partial element” is probably appropriate.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Well, yes, I suppose you're right. I've always strenuously resisted reading machine-specific formats like that, though, due to portability.

Comment: Yes, that's generally a good idea but I think the very reason the `fread` function accepts the size parameter is for reading in types other than `char`s. And doing this is not always bad. For example, if you have two processes running on the same machine that communicate via a pipe, using a binary format is perfectly fine.